# Rails app Heroku failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have an app that works locally but does does not work right on heroku. The root page loads, but when I try the submit link, Heroku gives me "We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

Looking at the logs, its seems like an asset issue and ive run "RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile" but I still get these log errors.

```
2014-09-22T01:09:39.694028+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-09-22 01:09:39] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-09-22T01:09:39.694047+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-09-22 01:09:39] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-      09-19) [x86_64-linux]
2014-09-22T01:09:39.694487+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-09-22 01:09:39] INFO      WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=24344
2014-09-22T01:09:39.797519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-09-22T01:09:40.724903+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=findmegnar.herokuapp.com request_id=502f7e98-22da-4825-ad85-77606ab64cca fwd="54.162.73.140" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=130ms status=200 bytes=1907
2014-09-22T01:09:44.875965+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=findmegnar.herokuapp.com request_id=900ca4d9-db6c-4c53-aeb4-f6e50c0a7e4f fwd="74.95.112.118" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=304 bytes=733
2014-09-22T01:09:44.978618+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-cb25950d0e442f07f1fa7be553c321c3.css" host=findmegnar.herokuapp.com request_id=13b510e0-f3c8-4f1a-8a29-9d99a30fb794 fwd="74.95.112.118" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=1829
2014-09-22T01:09:44.987883+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-433aac58cfba85b04e81533418015cc6.js" host=findmegnar.herokuapp.com request_id=2cbaa67e-646e-4faf-adee-c9c4606fe662 fwd="74.95.112.118" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=1829
2014-09-22T01:09:47.967521+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/searches" host=findmegnar.herokuapp.com request_id=2948d744-102f-420b-a856-63a55ab3e0c5 fwd="74.95.112.118" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

Edit: Further work found that this error was caused by lack of database. Running 
   heroku run rake db:reset
Fixed that issue. However, running 
    heroku run rake import:resorts

Did a rake import of the data I wanted to add to the data but did not actually add the data to the db.

Does anyone know if there is a special way to do rake tasks in heroku?

Comment: I seem to remember having to  run "rake assets:clean" then "rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development" before pushing to production fixed a problem.

Comment: apologies- above shold beENV=production

Comment: Log onto Herokuvia via development environment.  Thue se commands e.g. "heroku run rake assets:precompile"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Heroku**

If you're loading your database on `Heroku` again, you'll probably be best using the `rake db:schema:load` task - this builds the database from your `schema`, instead of your migrations.

```
#db/schema.rb
# If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch
```

To access Heroku functionality from your development command-line, you'll be best making use of the [Heroku Toolbelt](http://toolbelt.heroku.com) -

```
$ heroku run rake db:schema:load
$ heroku run ...
```

This enables you to perform Heroku actions from your development (local) machine. It routes your request *through* the Heroku API, allowing you to perform requests on the Heroku command-line as required

---

## Errors

If you're experiencing errors on Heroku, just as some information, you'll be best looking at how they work, and appreciating how to resolve them.

There are two types of error with Heroku:

**Heroku**

[image]

These are caused by your application not opening on Heroku itself

The problem here is that Heroku will have a certain set of "dependencies" which are required to run your application. These dependencies are in the form of the likes of your database, files, add-ons, `ENV` variables, etc.

If you don't have any of these available to your app, for whatever reason, you'll end up receiving the "platform" error as mentioned above. The fix for this is purely with Heroku - you need to ensure you have the files, settings & add-ons required to get your app working correctly

-

**Rails**

[image]

Rails errors are specific to your application, and are likely a result of bad syntax inside your application. The distinction here is that the `platform` error is going to be caused by *Heroku*, whilst the `Rails` error is going to be caused by *your app*.

If you're seeing the above error, the simplest way to resolve it is to locate the following file & change it **temporarily**:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.consider_all_requests_local = true # false
```

By pushing this to Heroku again, you'll be able to see the errors you had on your application through the standard Rails error-handling interface

Comment: Thank you this is for sure the issue and the best approach for solving it. I ended up going around about way by heroku run rake db:reset  rewriting the rake task to match heroku's scheduler plugin and then heroku run rake TASK_NAME to populate the database. Special thanks for the error handling information, it will come in handy!